# Set locale doesn't work in onCreate?

Tags: android, oncreate, setlocale

If I use this code "setLocale("de"); etc." with button click, it's work. But If I put in onCreate, it does't work. Could you fix for me? Thanks.

```
public void setLocale(String lang) {
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = 
    getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Comment: did you get any error message?

Comment: No, just it does't work.

Comment: can you show your onCreate method?

Comment: you should set Locale before setContentView method called.

Comment: Thanks everybody. Especially to Vikas, It's work now.